# C++ Linking cant find library on project migration from Unix to Linux

Tags: c++, linux, unix, linker, g++

After resolving all compilation errors due to migration, now there are Linker errors for libraries.

Original output is as follows (some names in project were replaced for obvious reasons):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
 (G) Linking module_name.o to make module_name
     LDOPTS set to:
  SHLIB Temp Path: /tmp/fbaSHLIBs020217035348fbamgr
     FBA libraries: -L/tmp/fbaSHLIBs020217035348fbamgr -lfba -lprocessControl
     Application libraries: -L/opt/app/fba/devl_rel_ver/bin/lib -lfba -lprojNameGenEdit -lprojNameTraceTool -lprojNameTables -lprojNameCommCcSc -lprojNamerecProc -lprojNameGenMap -lprojNameLogicalTracker -lprojNameCallCodes -lprojNameStrCodes -lprojNameFileVal -lprojNameReports -L -ltmi -L/opt/IBM/db2/V8.1/lib64  -ldb2
g++ -o module_name module_name.o \
                 \
                -I/opt/app/fba/devl_rel_ver/common \
                -L/tmp/fbaSHLIBs020217035348fbamgr -lfba -lprocessControl  \
                -L/opt/app/oraclnt/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/lib -lclntsh \
                `cat /opt/app/oraclnt/oracle/product/oraclient/lib/ldflags`  \
                `cat /opt/app/oraclnt/oracle/product/oraclient/lib/sysliblist` \
                -L/opt/app/fba/devl_rel_ver/bin/lib -lfba -lprojNameGenEdit -lprojNameTraceTool -lprojNameTables -lprojNameCommCcSc -lprojNamerecProc -lprojNameGenMap -lprojNameLogicalTracker -lprojNameCallCodes -lprojNameStrCodes -lprojNameFileVal -lprojNameReports -L$TMI_HOME -ltmi -L/opt/IBM/db2/V8.1/lib64  -ldb2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfba
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [module_name] Error 1
```

The files in the temp folder (also, with above name replacement done):

```
ls /tmp/fbaSHLIBs020217035348fbamgr
libfba.sl             libprojNameCallCodes.sl  libprojNameFileVal.sl  libprojNameGenMap.sl          libprojNamerecProc.sl  libprojNameStrCodes.sl  libprojNameTraceTool.sl
libprocessControl.sl  libprojNameCommCcSc.sl   libprojNameGenEdit.sl  libprojNameLogicalTracker.sl  libprojNameReports.sl  libprojNameTables.sl
```

What I tried:

1. FBALIB    = -L$(TEMP_SHLIB_DIR) $(TEMP_SHLIB_DIR)/libfba.sl $(TEMP_SHLIB_DIR)/libprocessControl.sl
2. List itemFBALIB    = -L$(TEMP_SHLIB_DIR) -llibfba.sl -llibprocessControl.sl
3. FBALIB    = -L$(TEMP_SHLIB_DIR) -l$(TEMP_SHLIB_DIR)/libfba.sl -lprocessControl

Nothing works!

Please, any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a file called libfba.so somewhere?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro No, just did locate on that... why? there is libfba.sl like I showed.

Comment: Because that's the file the linker looks for when you use -lfba

Comment: But I also tried to explicitly specify the file name...

Comment: No, that won't work, seems .sl files are not Linux shared library files, where did you get them from?

Comment: "Unix" is just a common name for many different variants and implementations of "Unix". Which specific "Unix" are you porting from? What is a `*.sl` file? How are those files related to libraries? Have you just copied the files from another platform and try to use them in your Linux system without any kind of conversion or rebuild?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro now that you've asked, I am not sure - I assumed they are generated in the code. I am looking into it and will update.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Migrating from HP-UX hostname B.11.11 U 9000/800 1388953032 unlimited-user license

Comment: These .sl libraries I am told are shared libraries (hence SL) - but I will update once I find out exactly where they are coming from....

Comment: @Carmageddon They are shared libraries, but they are not Linux shared libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems .sl files are HP-UX shared libraries, while linux uses the .so extension for shared libraries. Seems you copied the HP-UX libraries to Linux, and this is not going to work.

The only solution is to get equivalent library files for Linux, with the proper .so extension.